# Showing a tensor is non-zero without using universal property

Tags: tensor-products

The following question is from Vakil's The Rising Sea:
Show that $Z/(12)⊗Z/(10)≅Z/(2).$

It is clear that all tensors are equal to either $1⊗1$ or $0⊗0$. My question is that how one can show $1⊗1\neq 0⊗0 $ without using universal property of tensor products.

Comment: I assume the tensor product is over $\mathbb{Z}$. Is there a specific reason why you want to avoid using the universal property, which is the most important thing about tensor products?

Comment: I seriously think it is misguided to try to prove something about tensor products while explicitly ignoring the basic characterization... What do you _really_ want here?

Comment: Yes it is over ℤ. I avoid it because Vakil asked this before he introduced its universal property to give some hands-on practice with tensor products.